# How to change the error icon in MUI Stepper

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I need to to change the error icon of a MUI Stepper which is by default : [image]

But the expected icon is [image]

I know that I can use labelprops.StepIconComponent but I can't integrate it in the code

Here is the link of the Sandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontal...23olc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could try labelprops.StepIconComponent when there is an error. https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalstepperwitherror-demo-material-ui-forked-2bmexi?file=/demo.js:951-968

Comment: Thank you for your reponse , the problem is that I can not integrate it in my code

Comment: I updated the sandbox with changing the icons. You just need to account for errors and then render the specific icon if there is an error . https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalnonlinearstepper-demo-material-ui-forked-9gt6hn?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I'm assuming it worked ! If it's what you needed I'll put the answer back for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally change the icon on an MUI StepButton

https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalnonlinearstepper-demo-material-ui-forked-9gt6hn?file=/demo.tsx:2975-3132

```
        <StepButton
          icon={!completed[index] && <ErrorOutlined />}
          color="inherit"
          onClick={handleStep(index)}>
```